# Cómo sumar valores de Firebase con Swift

Tags: firebase, swift

tengo un problema... Quiero sumar los valores que viene de Firebase de CantidadPozole, este es mi código:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var suma: Int = 0
        let DatoGuardado = UserDefaults.standard
        DatoGuardado.value(forKey: "email")
        DatoGuardado.value(forKey: "username")
        DatoGuardado.synchronize()
        CorreoG = DatoGuardado.value(forKey: "email") as! String
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://antojitos-mexicanos.firebaseio.com").child("Pedidos")
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Correo").queryEqual(toValue: "\(CorreoG)")
        query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0
            {
                self.Historial.removeAll()
                for Cuenta in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]
                {
                    let CuentaObject = Cuenta.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let LocalName = CuentaObject? ["Local"]
                    let CantidadPozole = CuentaObject? ["CantidadPozole"]
                    let PasaHistorial = HistorialC(Localp: LocalName as! String?, CantidadPozolep: CantidadPozole as! String?)
                    self.Historial.append(PasaHistorial)
                    let imprime = Cuenta.childSnapshot(forPath: "CantidadPozole")
                    print("El valor de cada Pozole es \(String(describing: imprime.value))")
                }
                self.HistorialConexion.reloadData()
            print(suma) <- **Aquí debe aparecer el total**
            }
        })
    }
```

Aquí es donde llamo solo 2 valores "Local" y "CantidadPozole". Y en Firebase tengo en CantidadPozole solo números. Cuando mando a imprimir si me aparecen los datos de CantidadPozole pero yo quisiera sumarlos todos y al final imprimir el total.
Porfa, Echame una manita :D

Comment: Porqué no utilizas la variable `suma` que está declarada? Algo así `suma += CantidadPozole`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debe hacer es convertir los valores que le retornan de la base datos en un entero (INT) para que les pueda aplicar formulas matemáticas, en este caso al hacer **Int(CantidadPozole)! + Int(LocalName)!** lo que estamos haciendo es decirle que convierta estos valores en enteros, y al ser numerosos enteros los podemos sumar entre si, y otra cantidad mas de operaciones que se pueden aplicar. luego puede imprimir un resultado el cual retornara en calidad de entero (INT) pero si lo que quiere es un string puede hacer una interpolación del resultado o hacer una conversion de entero a texto así

```
{

 ....
 let LocalName = CuentaObject? ["Local"]
 let CantidadPozole = CuentaObject? ["CantidadPozole"] 
}
 
let suma = Int(CantidadPozole)! + Int(LocalName)!
print(suma)//imprime resultado en Entero
print("\(suma)") // imprime el resultado en string (interpolation method)
print(String(suma))// convierte el resultado de entero a string
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta llegara a funcionar, estaría mucho mejor que le explicaras a OP el porqué debería realizarlo de esa forma aunque parezca muy obvio es posible que para OP u otro usuario no lo sea. Saludos ;)